# How to get the right type of texture coordinate input in vertex shader in DX9

Tags: graphics, directx, hlsl, vertex-shader

Here are two version of HLSL vertex shader input

struct VS_INPUTS_0
{
    float3 Pos  : POSITION;
    float2 Tex0 : TEXCOORD0;
}

struct VS_INPUTS_1
{
    float3 Pos  : POSITION;
    float3 Tex0 : TEXCOORD0;
}

The only difference is the float2 and float3 of Tex0. Is there a DX9 API to get the right type of Tex0 to indicate whether the type of Tex0 is float2 or float3?

Answer (score 1):

For DX9, not as far as I know, as DX9 automatically patches your shaders. That is, if your pixel shader expects `float2` and your vertex shader provides `float3`, it will still work. With DirectX10/11, you can use shader reflection to query the compiled shader and figure out what it expects.

Question is: What do you mean with "right type"? That totally depends on your pixel shader, the vertex shader alone is not enough to decide.

Comment: Thanks. This question is not related with pixel shader I think, because I want to get the correct type information of vertex shader input.